# Mongo query condition using IN?

Tags: mongodb

I wonder if there's anything similar to mysql IN? Like this "where id in (1,3,5)"?

I have this in my group by condition and i want to do filter only certain ids and those ids are like the above case where using gte/lt once will be able to do the job.

Maybe not just for group by but find. Any help will be great. Thanks.

{"time" : {"$gte" : "2015-12-16", "$lt" : "2015-12-16"}}

Comment: db.collection.find( { _id : { $in : [1,3,5] } } ); https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/query/in/

Comment: @sparkmix generally it's a good idea to check the manual before asking a question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows zero attempt to solve the problem (or check the manual)

Answer (score 0):

You mean, like:

```
{ field: { $in: [1,3,5] } }
```

No.  There's nothing like that [in mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/in/). Trust me. Nothing like that.